# I want to prevent scrollTo on jQuery tab clicks

Tags: jquery

I have some simple tabs set up, but I can't figure out why the code is forcing a scroll to element on click. I don't believe I have that implemented anywhere, seems to be a default. Is there a way to prevent this so the tabs just switch on click with no movement?

My page is at [www.aceable.com/tab-test](http://www.aceable.com/tab-test)

Comment: could you give the code for the tab

Comment: i suspect this happens because of the  `href="#tab1"` in your links. Please try what happens if you remove the href attribute completely.

Answer (score 0):

if you create a anchor link like `href='#tab1'` the browser will try to scroll to an element with `id='tab1'`.

You should remove the href attribute completely and the scroll will not happen. It has nothing to do with your javascript tab code. It is the normal behaviour on anchor-links.